# percentage of filtered columns after applying groupBy in spark Dataframe

Tags: sql, scala, apache-spark, dataframe

A Spark Dataframe contains a table with 2 columns:
Status,Category.

```
Status has values----'y' and 'n'
Category has values -'a', 'b' and 'c'
```

How to find the percentage of status 'y' in each category in spark (Scala)?
I'm able to to upto this.

```
df.groupBy("category").agg(count("*"))
df.filter(col("status")==="y").groupBy("category").count()
```

After that combining anything gives me errors

Answer (score 0):

```
val dfN = df.filter(col("status").equalTo("y"))
```

[image]

```
val dfSum = dfN.groupBy("category").agg(count("status").as("Sum"))
val numSum = num.first()(0).toString.toInt

val dfResult = dfSum.select(col("category"), lit(col("Sum") * 100 / numSum).as("percentage"))
```

[image]

Comment: In this line, val numSum = num.first()(0).toString.toInt         ,what do you mean by num?

Comment: It is counting the number of ocurrences of status “y” in the df. For my example, it will bring the value of 4.

Comment: I guess it should be var num=df.groupBy("category").agg(count("*")).   I want the percentage of 'y' in each category

Comment: even then I get this error:                                                                         Name: java.lang.NumberFormatException
Message: For input string: "8.0"
StackTrace:   at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
  at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:580)
  at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:615)
  at scala.collection.immutable.StringLike$class.toInt(StringLike.scala:272)
  at scala.collection.immutable.StringOps.toInt(StringOps.scala:29)

Comment: Thats what it is giving to you:

Answer (score 0):

`GroupBy` and `aggregation` should be enough to find the `count` of each individual `Category` of each `Status`. `Window` function can be used to find the total `sum` of each `Category`. And finally you can do the calculation by `filter`ing out the necessary `Status`.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window

def windowSpec = Window.partitionBy("Category")
val tempdf = df.groupBy("Status", "Category").agg(count("Category").as("ind_count"))
                .withColumn("tot_count", sum("ind_count").over(windowSpec))

  tempdf.filter($"Status" === "y").select($"Status", $"Category", (($"ind_count"/$"tot_count")*100).as("y_percentage")).show(false)
```

I hope the answer is helpful

Comment: getting syntax error.  I have the imports. I'm running in apache toree.

Comment: def windowSpec = Window.partitionBy("Category")                                           After adding this line, I'm getting the error. apache toree is not printing the stack trace for this error                                                                            Name: Syntax Error.
Message: 
StackTrace:

Comment: what is the spark version you are using?

Comment: The latest one: 2.2.0

Comment: are you sure the error is on that line ? you can remove the window function and it use and see if the error still exists to confirm.